# How to use iChat as client for Google Talk with Google Apps account?

Tags: google-talk, ichat

I'm using Google Apps with my own domain name. However, the account is not usable with iChat for Google Talk because of this error:

> iChat can't log in to talk.google.com because your login ID or
>   password is incorrect.

Of course, I tried several time with correct password. I'm sure that my password is correct because I could log into my Apps service with the same password.

Does any additional configuration required on server or client to use iChat as XMPP client for Google Talk with Google Apps account?

Currently, all client configurations are default, and I don't know about server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the account type, you should use Jabber instead of Google Talk. For "server", use `talk.google.com`. For "port", 5223 is what I used. Check the "Use SSL" checkbox. Other configuration options are as you've done. I hope it works for you. I personally prefer Adium over iChat for all my IM accounts. =)